# MongoDB Structure for messaging part of project with full features (delete from one user specially)

Tags: php, database, laravel, mongodb, schema

I am trying to build a messaging part in my project but I have a problem with the best design for messaging collections **which enables me to delete a message or conversation from a one user (if he wants) or create an index for user conversations**

I have found many examples of similar things, but I did not find the design is able to meet the best performance of this requirements

**Edit:**
I am trying the pattern

```
   Conversations: {
        id: 1111,
        participants: ['user1', 'user2']
        }
    
    Messages: { 
        sender: 'user1',
        content: 'good u',
        time_created: new Date(),
        converstationId: 1111
        }
```

but in this case there is a problem with delete meessage from one user and problem  with indexing conversations by users id

any recommended solutions?!

Comment: With Mongo, you normally try to store everything within a single document and denormalization is expected. How are you storing the messages and what have you experimented with?

Comment: @Devon I was edit the post. I don't store all conversation in one document

Comment: You're using mongodb as a relational db which is an antipattern for them.  Might want  to rethink your tool or your design.